# Renaming directories

Tags: batch-rename, termux

I've got like 230 directories of this kind (1367018589_name_nameb_namec_named) and would like to rename them into (Name Nameb Namec Named).

To be more precise:

1. Removing numbers
2. Replacing underscores with spaces (except the first understore which comes after the numbers)
3. First letter into capital letter

a easy one-liner is preferred since I'm quite a newbie regarding Linux and bash.
Bash script wouldn't be a problem either - just a small explanation how to use it would be very much appreciated.
Meaning that I can understand once I know the command, but having troubles coming up with in my own.

Much thanks in andvance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one line (updated to capitalize first letter of each word -- missed that the first time):

`$ for f in * ; do g=$(echo $f | sed s/[0-9_]*//  | sed s/_/\ /g | sed "s/\b\(.\)/\u\1g") ; echo "mv \"$f\" to \"$g\"" ; done`

Once you are happy that it is going to do what you want change

```
echo "mv \"$f\" to \"$g\""
```

to

```
mv -i "$f" "$g"
```

Note, the `-i` option is to avoid the case of accidentally overwriting a file (say if you had files `123_test` and `345_test` for instance)

Comment: as for 3) (gotta correct myself: uppercase every first letter) I've used (which I've googled and modified your oneliner accordingly): for f in * ; do g=$(echo $f | sed -e "s/\b\(.\)/\u\1/g") ; echo "mv \"$f\" to \"$g\"" ; done

Comment: mv: cannot move 'gedemo zerzura city state' to a subdirectory of itself, 'Gedemo Zerzura City State/gedemo zerzura city state'

Comment: that's the error though

Comment: kinda obvious ... need to rename it and not moving it

Comment: `for f in * ; do g=$(echo $f | sed -e "s/\b\(.\)/\u\1/g") ; echo "rename \"$f\" to \"$g\"" ; done` works as intended and right echo output but when doing `for f in * ; do g=$(echo $f | sed -e "s/\b\(.\)/\u\1/g") ; rename -i "$f" "$g" ; done` it throws `rename: not enough arguments` ... what's wrong here?

Comment: `mv` is the standard rename in linux/unix. `rename` is similar but uses perl expressions and different options. Compare `man mv` with `man rename`.

Comment: for `mv: cannot move 'x' to a subdirectory of itself, 'X/x', are you using bash on windows? I think that is a bug in that version.

Comment: Also, I would run the command as shown above (the edited one, and with the echo) and look for 'gedemo zerzura city state' and make sure it is matching they way you expect.

Comment: I'm using termux
Thanks for your reply - I'll leave it for now as it is (the numbers and the underscores are gone and that's the most important thing I need) and will later look into that uppercase thing

Comment: `for f in * ; do g=$(echo $f | sed -e "s/\b\(.\)/\u\1/g") ; mv "$f" "renamed/$g" ; done` did the trick since `filename` & `FileName` are seen as the same ... just wanted closing this here in case somebody else is interested ... it'll throw `cannot move 'renamed' to a subdirectory of itself, 'renamed/Renamed'` but that can be ignored